# Socket.io emit NOT going to all clients

Tags: sockets, socket.io

There are a lot of socket.io questions on here but I haven't seen this one before. Basically, I am building an app where I'd like to have two people join and at that point launch them into a game.

The problem is that `socket.emit` is only sending to one user (the last user who triggers the event) and not the other. I can actually emit to the other user if I also use `socket.broadcast.emit`, but I should not have to do this. My understanding is that both clients should receive any emitted messages, and broadcast.emit should be restricted to all clients except the initiator. Here's my code (I've commented out the line that sends it to both clients:

```
const app = require('express')()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
const constants = require('./constants')
const draft = require('./game/draft')
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000  ",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
      }
})

// auth middleware
io.use((socket, next) => {
    const username = socket.handshake.auth.username;
    if (!username) {
        return next(new Error("invalid username"));
    }
    socket.username = username;
    next();
});

// connections
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    if (io.engine.clientsCount > constants.CONNECTION_LIMIT) {
        socket.emit('err', { message: 'reach the limit of connections' })
        socket.disconnect()
        console.log('Disconnected...')
        return
    }
})

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    const users = [];
    for (let [id, socket] of io.of("/").sockets) {
      users.push({
        userID: id,
        username: socket.username,
      });
    }
    socket.emit("users", users);
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("user connected", {
      userID: socket.id,
      username: socket.username,
    });
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    if (io.engine.clientsCount === 2) {
        socket.emit('START_GAME', { message: 'both players have joined the lobby' })
        // socket.broadcast.emit('START_GAME', { message: 'both players have joined the lobby' })
        const {player1comps, player2comps} = draft.startDraft()
    }

})
```

[image]

As you can see the emit is going to just ONE of the clients. And the server is obviously aware that there are two clients since it can't fire that function until it sees two. Super weird, since the docs are very, very clear that `socket.emit` should go to all, unlike `socket.broadcast.emit`

Answer (score 0):

After posting on their github I found out that there is a way to send to all, but it's extremely will hidden in the docs imo:

`io.sockets.emit` is what you want to use.